# Nginx reverse proxy when redirect stay in same domain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I've configured a nginx vhost to use some requests on a domain and some other in another one. I want to show only the final result without let users know the existing of both two versions.

For example, some sections from http://old.website.com and http://new.website.com are merged in http://www.website.com.

Everything is working fine but when there is a 301 or 302 with a full path it will redirect to http://old.website.com or http://new.website.com.

Is there any way to avoid the redirect?

PS: I can't change old or new by now.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy_redirect` is supposed to solve this kind of problems. The exact directive depends on your Nginx configuration, e.g. what `location`s you use, etc.

The documentation is [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect)